# 'Undefined' when accessing JSON value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to access the "pages" value in my JSON, but get an 'undefined' value trying to so.

My code

```
var fs = require('fs');
 
var contents = fs.readFileSync('jsonformatter.json', 'utf8');
var jsonContents = JSON.stringify(contents);

function escapeSpecialChars(jsonString) {

    return jsonString.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
        .replace(/\r/g, "\\r")
        .replace(/\t/g, "\\t")
        .replace(/\f/g, "\\f");
}

escapeSpecialChars(jsonContents)
var jsonContents = JSON.parse(jsonContents);


console.log(jsonContents.pages);
```

A snippet of my JSON (Would include all, but its 20,000 + lines)

```
{"uri": "",
  "mimeType": "application/pdf",
  "text": "6/17/2020 sample-auto-insurance-declarations-page_1_2x.jpg (1200×1974)\n)\nPolicygenius\nPolicy Number 12345-67-89\nAuto Insurance Declaration Page\n$79848\nFARMERS tt\nPolicy Premium and Fees\nINSURANCE\nPolicy Information\nPremium/Fees\nPolicy Number\nEffective\nExpiration\nNamed Insured(s)\nPolicy Premium\nFees\n$797.60\n$0.88\nPolicy Premium Fees\n$798.48\nAddress\nCity\nUnderwritten by\n12345-67-89\n01/01/2019 12:01 AM\n06/01/2019 12:01 AM\nJack Smith\nJane Smith\n1234 Main St\nBrooklyn, NY 11211\nFarmers Insurance\n6301 Owensmouth Ave.\nWoodland Hills, CA 91367\nTHIS IS NOT A BILL.\nYour bill with the amount due will be mailed separately.\nHousehold Drivers\nAll persons who drive or will occasionally be driving any of the cars on the policy should be listed below. If\nanyone is missing or needs to be added, such as a newly licensed driver, you should contact your agent or\nthe company to add that person before they begin to drive any of the cars covered on the policy.\nName\nJack Smith\nJack Smith Jr.\nDriver Status\nCovered\nCovered\nName\nJane Smith\nDriver Status\nCovered\nVehicle Information\nVeh. #\n1\nYear/Make/Model/VIN\n2019 Porsche Macan 4D 4WD\nWP1A A1234567890\nCoverage\nComprehensive\nCollision\nAdditional Equipment\nDeductible\n$500\n$1,000\nLimit\nACV\nACV\n$1,000\nCoverage Information\nCoverage\nBodily Injury\nProperty Damage\nPermissive User Limit of Liability\nMedical Coverage\nUninsured Motorist Bodily Injury\nLimits\n$250K each person/$500K each incident\n$100K each incident\nFull\n$5,000 each person\n$250K each person/$500K each incident\nVehicle 1\n$301.50\nIncluded\n$17.00\n$66.50\n$44.50\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/3uw9cov4u60w/6bEiFWZKj35DFMeNXvWsLV/e8e322c241bb5e860f0c26bf9cd8ec8d/sample-auto-insurance-declarations… 1/1\n",
  "pages": [
    {
      "pageNumber": 1,
      "dimension": {
        "width": 612,
        "height": 792,
        "unit": "points"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: There is no need to `JSON.stringify` a JSON string, it already is stringified. And what are you trying to do with that `escapeSpecialChars` function?

Comment: The result of your `escapeSpecialChars` function is discarded since you don't assign the return value to anything. If you did use it, it would cause `JSON.parse` to error, since it does not at all expect strings like `\n` to suddenly appear in the JSON. Not sure the function is useful.

Comment: Really all you need to do is `var contents = fs.readFileSync('jsonformatter.json', 'utf8'; var jsonContents = JSON.parse(contents);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @str certainly makes a good argument, you could do something like this if you wanted:

```js
/**
 * Made some modifications to the `escapeSpecialChars` function
 */

const contents = makeJsonData();

// REMOVED
/** const strContents = JSON.stringify(contents); **/
/** const jsonContents = escapeSpecialChars(strContents); **/

const jsonContents = escapeSpecialChars(contents); 

// REMOVED
/** const parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonContents); **/
/** console.log(parsedJson.pages); **/

console.log(jsonContents.pages);


/**
 * Helper Functions
 */
 
function escapeSpecialChars(jsonData = {}) { // <-- Pass in JSON, let the function stringify (as well as parse) the data..
  const jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  
  const cleanedStr = jsonString.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
    .replace(/\r/g, "\\r")
    .replace(/\t/g, "\\t")
    .replace(/\f/g, "\\f");
    
  return JSON.parse(cleanedStr);
}

function makeJsonData() { // Helper function to make things a little more legible
  return {
    "uri": "",
    "mimeType": "application/pdf",
    "text": "6/17/2020 sample-auto-insurance-declarations-page_1_2x.jpg (1200×1974)\n)\nPolicygenius\nPolicy Number 12345-67-89\nAuto Insurance Declaration Page\n$79848\nFARMERS tt\nPolicy Premium and Fees\nINSURANCE\nPolicy Information\nPremium/Fees\nPolicy Number\nEffective\nExpiration\nNamed Insured(s)\nPolicy Premium\nFees\n$797.60\n$0.88\nPolicy Premium Fees\n$798.48\nAddress\nCity\nUnderwritten by\n12345-67-89\n01/01/2019 12:01 AM\n06/01/2019 12:01 AM\nJack Smith\nJane Smith\n1234 Main St\nBrooklyn, NY 11211\nFarmers Insurance\n6301 Owensmouth Ave.\nWoodland Hills, CA 91367\nTHIS IS NOT A BILL.\nYour bill with the amount due will be mailed separately.\nHousehold Drivers\nAll persons who drive or will occasionally be driving any of the cars on the policy should be listed below. If\nanyone is missing or needs to be added, such as a newly licensed driver, you should contact your agent or\nthe company to add that person before they begin to drive any of the cars covered on the policy.\nName\nJack Smith\nJack Smith Jr.\nDriver Status\nCovered\nCovered\nName\nJane Smith\nDriver Status\nCovered\nVehicle Information\nVeh. #\n1\nYear/Make/Model/VIN\n2019 Porsche Macan 4D 4WD\nWP1A A1234567890\nCoverage\nComprehensive\nCollision\nAdditional Equipment\nDeductible\n$500\n$1,000\nLimit\nACV\nACV\n$1,000\nCoverage Information\nCoverage\nBodily Injury\nProperty Damage\nPermissive User Limit of Liability\nMedical Coverage\nUninsured Motorist Bodily Injury\nLimits\n$250K each person/$500K each incident\n$100K each incident\nFull\n$5,000 each person\n$250K each person/$500K each incident\nVehicle 1\n$301.50\nIncluded\n$17.00\n$66.50\n$44.50\nhttps://images.ctfassets.net/3uw9cov4u60w/6bEiFWZKj35DFMeNXvWsLV/e8e322c241bb5e860f0c26bf9cd8ec8d/sample-auto-insurance-declarations… 1/1\n",
    "pages": [{
      "pageNumber": 1,
      "dimension": {
        "width": 612,
        "height": 792,
        "unit": "points"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude you rock! Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @Cubonezx if my answer resolved your issue, please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer (and throw me an upvote if you feel it's necessary) :)